# How can I highlight specific labels in a dendrogram?

Tags: r, dendrogram, hclust, dendextend

I made a cluster analysis using simple following code

```
hc2 = hclust(dist(geno.imp))
pdf(file="file.pdf", width=50)
plot(hc2,cex=0.2) 
dev.off()
```

I want to highlight some of the specific leaves (not the nodes). I have the list of those leaves in a separate vector. How do I do highlight only specific leaves, keeping all other leaves black?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `?dendrapply`. `dendrapply` allows you to apply a function to each node of a `dendrogram`. In that function you could change the properties of the node, e.g.:

```
## create some example data
set.seed(1)
highlight <- rownames(USArrests)[sample(nrow(USArrests), 10)]

## function to change color etc. of a leaf
colorLeafs <- function(x) {
  if (is.leaf(x) && attr(x, "label") %in% highlight) {
    attr(x, "nodePar") <- list(lab.col="red", pch=NA)
  }
  return(x)
}

hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")

dd <- dendrapply(as.dendrogram(hc), colorLeafs)

plot(dd)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi sgibb, thank you for your answer. I just gave a more detailed answer based on the dendextend package. I would appreciate it if you could give your feedback on my answer. With regards, Tal

Comment: @TalGalili: The *dendextend* package is great (and I didn't know it in April 2014) and makes this example much easier.

Answer (score 2):

sgibb answer is a good one for a specific case. What you could also try is using the [dendextend](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/) package, designed exactly for this sort of thing.

Here are two ways in which you would get the same result as in the example of sgibb:

```
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave"))
## create some example data
set.seed(1)
highlight <- rownames(USArrests)[sample(nrow(USArrests), 10)]

install.packages("dendextend")
library(dendextend)
# create a dendrogram with colored labels:
dend2 <- color_labels(dend, labels = highlight , col = 2) 
# ploting it
plot(dend2)

# Here is a second way for doing the same thing:
dend2 <- color_labels(dend, col = ifelse(labels(dend) %in% highlight, 2, 1)) 
plot(dend2)
```

[image]